# How to catch user leaving a page and cancelling it

Tags: gwt

When a user leaves the GWT app, I would like to open a confirm dialog and offer them the choice to stay, i.e. Confirm("are you sure you want to leave this page", "yes", "no").

I know how to build the dialbox. :)

The question is, how to I catch the event of a user leaving the page and how to I cancel it?

Daniel

Comment: Navigating away from the page or exiting out of the browser?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call [Window.addWindowClosingHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#addCloseHandler(com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.CloseHandler)), and pass it a callback that calls [setMessage](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.ClosingEvent.html#setMessage(java.lang.String)) on the Window.ClosingEvent, like so:

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
      public void onWindowClosing(Window.ClosingEvent closingEvent) {
        closingEvent.setMessage("Do you really want to leave the page?");
      }
    });
```

(I've put in links to the GWT 2.0 docs; change the 2.0 to 1.6 in those URLs to see the GWT 1.6/1.7 docs.)

Note that doing it this way, you don't have to/don't get to create the dialog box yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a CloseHandler and register it on the Window:

`Window.addWindowClosingHandler(handler)`

EDIT: Fixed method name. See aem comment and answer.

Comment: I don't think that method exists?  Do you mean addWindowCloseListener?

Comment: addWindowCloseListener is deprecated since GWT 1.6. You should use Window.addCloseHandler(handler) or Window.addClosingHandler(handler) instead.

Comment: Isac, instead of making a comment on your answer, you can just edit it to mention the current function.

Comment: This won't do what the question asks, because addCloseHandler passes you a CloseEvent, which happens when it's too late to close the window. addWindowClosingHandler lets you do what the question asks. See http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.ClosingEvent.html and http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/CloseEvent.html

Comment: What if I only want to know when the last window of my wepabb is closed? Let's say the user opens a bunch of tabs, I want to know when he closes the last one, how can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

Call the method below in the `onModuleLoad()`.

```
 private void setupHistory() {
        final String initToken = History.getToken();
        if (initToken.length() == 0) {
            History.newItem("main");
        }

        // Add history listener
        HandlerRegistration historyHandlerRegistration = History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                String token = event.getValue();
                if (initToken.equals(token)) {
                    History.newItem(initToken);
                }
            }
        });

        // Now that we've setup our listener, fire the initial history state.
        History.fireCurrentHistoryState();

        Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler() {
            boolean reloading = false;

            @Override
            public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
                if (!reloading) {
                    String userAgent = Window.Navigator.getUserAgent();
                    if (userAgent.contains("MSIE")) {
                        if (!Window.confirm("Do you really want to exit?")) {
                            reloading = true;
                            Window.Location.reload(); // For IE
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        event.setMessage("My App"); // For other browser
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```