# Execute code on window close in GWT

Tags: java, events, gwt

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
        event.setMessage("Really?");

        // If user clicks 'ok' in the dialog, execute code below. Else skip the code and return to window.

        // CODE that does stuff goes here.
    }
});
```

How do I capture the input from the dialog?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193098/how-to-catch-user-leaving-a-page-and-cancelling-it

Comment: Well, not really. What I want to do differs since I want to be able to execute code when the Ok button is clicked and not when the cancel button is clicked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There need to be two handlers, one `Window.ClosingHandler` and one `CloseHandler`. See below. This will make sure, if 'cancel' is clicked in the dialog, the `CloseHandler` isn't triggered. But if 'ok' is clicked, the `CloseHandler` is executed and will run the necessary code. This could be used for releasing db locks, neatly closing open sessions, etc.

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
        event.setMessage("You sure?");
    }
});

Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {

    @Override
    public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {
        //Execute code when window closes!
    }
});
```

Comment: What if you want to execute some code when the user doesn't go on to close the window?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into Window.Confirm for this kind of functionality.

You can read up on it here:
[gwt.user.client.Window](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html)

Comment: Well, i've tried that, but despite what you choose in the confirm dialog, it will close the window. I want the window to stay open when the cancel button is pressed.

I can for example do a 


if(Window.confirm("Really"){ 
  do stufff 
}else{
   stop closing window
}  

the only way I know how to stop it from closing is to call the setMessage() method on the event. This will pop up yet another dialog..... which if I click cancel will stop the window from closing, but that's really ugly. I want to be able to use just one dialog.