# GWT end Http Session on Window close

Tags: session, gwt

When I close my browser window with my app open, I would like to end the http session as well.
I have tried [Execute code on window close in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562658/execute-code-on-window-close-in-gwt) but anything I place in the onClose method doesn't get run.

```
Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event)
        {
            //Code in here never executes!
            alert("Hi");
            Window.Location.replace(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "logout.jsp");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two methods you can use:

- **Window.addWindowClosingHandler**: Registers for `ClosingEvent`, which is fired by JavaScript's `$wnd.onbeforeunload`.
- **Window.addCloseHandler**: Registers for `CloseEvent`, which is fired by JavaScript's `$wnd.onunload`.

see `WindowImpl.initWindowCloseHandler()`, and also `WindowImplIE`

The ClosingEvent is fired a little bit earlier than the CloseEvent.

(There's a third method, `Window.addWindowCloseListener`, which effectively registers both for `$wnd.onbeforeunload` and `$wnd.onunload`, but that method is deprecated.)

The reason why you don't see the alert is probably explained with the javadoc of `ClosingHandler.onWindowClosing()`:

```
 * Fired just before the browser window closes or navigates to a different
 * site. No user-interface may be displayed during shutdown.
```

And instead of `Window.location.replace()` you should rather make an ajax call for the logout (e.g. using GWT-RPC, or RequestBuilder). The user closes the window, so it can't replace its location anymore.