# Where should resources-clearing code be in a GWT application?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

Good day everybody!

I'm developing web application on GWT framework. I created a special servlet where I implemented async methods. In the servlet `init()` method I created connection pool and I want do destroy it on application close() event.

In the build-in methods for servlets called `destroy()` I put my code responsible for resources clearing but it seems it never runs.

Where I should clear resources or how I can force destroy() method? Just closing web browser doesn't help. `init()` runs but `destroy()` doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing two things here.

Have a look at the [JavaDoc for `Servlet.destroy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#destroy%28%29) - it specifically states *"Called by the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the servlet is being taken out of service"*, which does not imply that closing a browser will call this method. Stopping or otherwise forcing a complete refresh of the *container* will, though.

What might be more relevant to you is the [`WindowCloseListener`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/WindowCloseListener.html) - you can implement the `onWindowClosed()` to call an RPC method to clean up on your backend, Just remember to re-setup the pools on next `EntryPoint.onModuleLoad()`!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

In a java servlet, `destroy()` is not supposed to be called by the programmer. But, if it is invoked, it gets executed. The implicit question is, will the servlet get destroyed? No, it will not. The `destroy()` method is not supposed to and will not destroy a java servlet.

Look at [Execute code on window close in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562658/execute-code-on-window-close-in-gwt)