# GWT - Show a custom dialog before window close?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I need to prompt the user to a site usability survey when the user navigate away from the site or try to close the site window. For example, when the user closes the window of my site, I want to show a prompt to say "do you want to take a survey?" , if the user clicks yet, open a new window with the survey link.

Is there a way in GWT to achieve that?

I have tried using 
Windows.addWindowCLosingHandler

but that only gave me the ability to set a message to ask if the user want to stay on the site or now using ClosingEvent event , event.setMessage("sure?");

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.onunload` but that will be called whenever the user changes the page

Also see here: [How to catch user leaving a page and cancelling it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2193098/561731)

Answer (score 0):

Use the unload method on the body:

```
<body onUnload="unloadFunction(); return false;">
```

Then something like this for your js:

```
function unloadFunction()
 {
     if (confirm("Would you like to take our servey?"))
     {
          window.location.href = 'location_of_your_survey'
     }

     return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to show a customized gwt dialog, not the ugly javascript confirmation prompt

Comment: Just put the GWT dialog in the unloadFunction above