# GWT refresh and reload with the current view or logout

Tags: java, gwt

I am developing a GWT Application, In that I want to browser refresh. I implement this handler. I need to call one method from overridden method.
This time if I call the method then the reload doesn't work

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler(){ 
    @Override 
    public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) { 
        event.setMessage("If you leave or refresh this page, " + 
            "you will be logged out of " + 
            "this application. Confirm that you want to do that.");
    }

});
```

Comment: I think it could be a possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193098/how-to-catch-user-leaving-a-page-and-cancelling-it) BTW the formatting is not proper.